# Where to put NULL-Values in PHP-Docs? At the end?

Tags: php, types, coding-style, standards, phpdoc

Just a short question about PHP-Docs and NULL-Values.

I found these links about this:

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html or http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html

But they dont mention the order of the types. So its free to choose?

I do it like this for now:

```
/**
 * @param integer|null $a
 * @return array|null Array if succeed, NULL on Error
 */
function test($a = null)
{
    if($noValueFoundOrSomething)
        return null;

    return array();
}
```

but some people do it like this:

```
/**
 * @param null|integer $a
 * @return null|array Array if succeed, NULL on Error
 */
function test($a = null)
{
    if($noValueFoundOrSomething)
        return null;

    return array();
}
```

Maybe its free to choose but what is the best practice? Is there any standard about where to put the NULL-Value in PHP-Docs?

Comment: I start with explaining the actual parameter and then pointing out what default value will be used if NULL is passed. But there could be an argument made for first putting in the expected/common use-case; and that might be that you expect or even encourage coders not to fiddle with the parameter but use the NULL->default.

Comment: You do it right. In first place i need to know type of variable if i want to pass any value. Null is used if i dont want to pass anything right? So null information is second one. This is my opinion

Comment: If there is no specific clause about the order, then it's likely you can do whatever you want.